# iOS ionic2: How to send http request to different port than 80 / 443 (https)

Tags: ios, cordova, http, ionic2

I have problem - when i compile and run my ionic2 app on my iPhone i'am unable to get data from my restful api: `http://my-api.com:8082/api/v1`

The second problem is that I even unable to get error(!) - i run this:

```
this.http.get('http://my-api.com:8082/api/v1/users')
    .map( res => res.json() )
    .subscribe( result => { .. }, err => { .. })
```

but get nothing - no error, no result - on iphone :(

In `ionic lab` everything works fine - full access

**UPDATE**

Below i 'check' right answer but I wanna tell more about this topic - may be this will be helpful to others. I wanna make step further and try to use service that I run LOCALy using subdomain `my-api.dev:8082` (i change `hosts` file).

So to have visible this service in you iOS device you should edit `config.xml` file and find line(s) similar to this:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.8.101:8100" />
```

This is the IP (it can vary on different computers) adress of your localhost used by webserver with angular application used by ionic2 for hot-module-replacement (HMR). So to have access to your LOCAL api use its PORT and above IP and write in `config.xml` line like this:

```
<allow-intent href="http://192.168.8.101:8082/*" />
```

And use this address in your api angular providers (you can keep this adress in separate .env.ts file to easily change it in on one place depends of app build you wanna make: test,prod,local). After that you can build and run your app using HMR by:

```
ionic cordova run ios -l
```

(you don't need to kill and run again above command when you edit your config.xml file - changes will be updated automatically)

Comment: Regarding the second issue, `.map( res => { res.json})` is not returning anything, it should be `.map( res => res.json)`or `.map( res => { return res.json })`

Comment: ofcourse - i write example from head-  now is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first problem
Try with installing `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
$ cordova prepare
```

Then add following line to `config.xml`

```
<allow-intent href="http://my-api.com:8082/*"/>
```

I think if you overcome the first problem second one also will solve

Comment: it works - thank you :) - I also update my question on how to connect also to api on localhost